# Dispalying route travelled using latitude and longitude values in map

Tags: android, android-maps

I have an android app which will continuously send location information to server (latitude and longitude values). Another application will retrieve these info and display it in textview.

What I need to do is in my second app which displays in text view I need to add a mapview which displays the location tarvelled by marking it on map using the latitude and longitude values.

How to do it ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: How to do what.? everything.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj No i have almost everything. Read my question.. I need to mark the locations on map..

Comment: you should elaborate your question a bit more. have you fetched the location information.? have you been able to send that information to server.? have you retreived that map view on server.? How you want to mark that points in map view.?

Comment: Ya i fetched the location information and I am able to send it to server. I just made a textview to display the latitud,longitude and address details.. I have no idea on how to mark those information in server on map.

Answer (score 0):

As you have fetched the location information, now you just need to mark points on the map view to show the desired location on map view, You should follow [using google maps android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Here you will find a good example on how to add markers on mapview.

Comment: should I need to store those location details in database ? so that all location info's will be saved by which i can find the route..

Comment: why dont you use shared preferences to store location details.

Comment: I am a newbie in android field.. I have no idea about shared preference.. Lemme check about it..